# Find the co-ordinates of the point of intersection

Tags: coordinate-systems, differential

I have the function $$y=2x^2-3x$$  How do I find the co-ordinates of the point of intersection of the lines tangent to the curve at $y=-1$?

One point where $y = -1$ is when $x = \dfrac 12$.

I took the derivative of the given $y$:  $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 4x- 3$, then found slope at $x = \dfrac 12$. So slope of the tangent line is $-1$.

So the equation of tangent is $y+1=-1\left(x-\dfrac 12\right)$.

How to solve it further?

Comment: can you fix your $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: Set $y=-1$ to find $x$

Comment: i will get x=1/2

Comment: but i have the find the co-ordinates of the point of the intersection of tangent

Comment: Why the down-votes? The OP certainly showed effort, in the right direction. It seems the OP struggles as best s/he can with English. I edited it help show the flow of OPs ideas, and to express them in a way that might better be understood. This site is becoming too unwelcoming, too judgemental, to elitist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve for $x$ when $y = -1$: $$2x^2 - 3x = -1 \iff 2x^2 - 3x + 1 = 0 \iff (2x-1)(x-1) = 0 \implies x = \frac 12 \text{ or } x = 1$$

So, there are two points corresponding to $y = -1$: $\left(\frac 12, -1\right), (1, - 1)$.

Perhaps you need to find the point of intersection of the line tangent to the first point, with the line tangent to the second point.

Indeed, you've found the equation of the line tangent to the point $\left(\frac 12, -1\right)$, since $-1 = \dfrac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac 12\right)$: $$y+1= -\left(x -\frac 12\right)\iff y = -x -\frac 12\tag{1}$$

Now we need to find the equation of the line tangent to $(1, -1)$. $$\frac{dy}{dx}(1) = 4(1)-3 = 1$$

So the equation of the second line is given by $$y +1 = x-1 \iff y = x-2\tag{2}$$

Now, put $y$ from $(1)$ equal to $y$ from $(2)$, and solve for $x$, the x coordinate of the point of intersection. Then solve for $y$ using the equation for either line.

Comment: great this the proper answer brother

Comment: thank you you are a life saver